# How to select IMAP acc in vba Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

I have a problem, the macro below checks if there is a mail title from the sender. The problem is that in outlook, I have 2 accounts: IMAP and Exchange. Makro always chooses exchange. Where's the reason?

```
 Sub srchmail()

Dim Itms As Items
Dim srchSender As String
Dim srchSubject As String
Dim strFilterBuild As String
Dim ItmsBuild As Items
Dim strFilter As String

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")


Set sub_olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set sub_olFolder = sub_olFolder.Folders("SUBFOLDER")
Set Itms = sub_olFolder.Items

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Itms.Count
Next


srchSender = "SENDERMAIL"
srchSubject = "SUBJECTMAIL"


strFilter = "[SenderName] = '" & srchSender & "' And [Subject] = '" & srchSubject & "' And [SentOn] > '" & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & "'"


Set Itms = Itms.Restrict(strFilter)
If Itms.Count = 0 Then


    MsgBox "dont mail in " & sub_olFolder & " with sub:'" & srchSubject & "' on " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    Else


    MsgBox "found mail in " & sub_olFolder & " with sub: '" & srchSubject & "' on  " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
End If
ExitRoutine:
    Set Itms = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added comments to my answer and have updated it.  I do not know if you are told about those comments or the update.  I know you will be told about this comment so this makes sure you know to look again at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is:

```
Set sub_olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

You can only have one default Inbox.  Your default Inbox is clearly in the Exchange account.  You will need to explicitly name the IMAP store to access its Inbox.

When you look at your folder pane, you will see something like this:

```
Xxxxxxxxxxx
    Drafts
    Deleted Items
    Inbox
            :    :
Yyyyyyyyy
    Drafts
    Deleted Items
    Inbox
       SUBFOLDER
            :    :
```

Xxxxxxxxxxx and Yyyyyyyyy are the names of stores.  Stores are the files in which Outlook saves all your emails, calendar items, tasks and so on.  As I understand it, you MUST have one store per account.  You can also have as many extra stores as you wish.  I have stores named for my two accounts, “Archive”, “Test” and many more.

Try:

```
Set sub_olFolder = objNS.Folders("Yyyyyyyyy").Folders("Inbox")
```

Where “Yyyyyyyyy” is the name of the store (as it appears in the folder pane) containing the sub folder you wish to access.

I should perhaps add that I would have written:

```
Set Itms = Session.Folders("Yyyyyyyyy").Folders("Inbox").Folders("SUBFOLDER").Items
```

“Session” and “NameSpace” are supposed to be identical.  I use Session because it avoids the need to create a namespace and because a long time ago I had a failure with NameSpace that I could not diagnose.

Unless you need to access the store or Inbox or SUBFOLDER in some other way, you do not need variables for them.  Starting with the ultimate parent (Session) you can string the names of children, grandchildren and so on to any depth.

Be careful stringing properties together like this.  (1) It can take a little time to get the string correct.  (2) I have seen example of property strings where it is really difficult to determine what it being accessed.  If you return to this macro in 12 months, will you remember what this string means?  If someone else has to maintain your macro, will they understand what you have done?  If in doubt, keep it simple.

**Added because of error in original answer**

It is not possible for me to test my answer.  Try the following as a way for you to test my suggestion.

Replace "Yyyyyyyyy" in the following by the name of your IMAP store and then type it in your Immediate Window.

```
? Session.Folders("Yyyyyyyyy").Name
```

The interpreter should respond with the name of the IMAP store.  If that works, try:

```
? Session.Folders("Yyyyyyyyy").Folders("Inbox").Name
```

The interpreter should respond Inbox.  If that works, try:

```
? Session.Folders("Yyyyyyyyy").Folders("Inbox").Folders("SUBFOLDER").Name
```

The interpreter should respond SUBFOLDER.  If that works, try:

```
? Session.Folders("Yyyyyyyyy").Folders("Inbox").Folders("SUBFOLDER").Items(1).ReceivedTime
```

The interpreter should respond with the date and time of the older email in the subfolder.  If that works, my answer should work.  If any of the above doesn't work, please respond with a detailed explanation of what failed

Comment: @Lunar Wolf responded to the answers by adding his own answer.  That answer was deleted because [s]he should have responded by comment.  The response to this answer was: "Tony Dallimore I try to use your solution, but doesn't work. :("

Comment: @Lunar Wolf.  You do not say what was wrong with my answer but having studied it, I realise I omitted Inbox from the chain.  Sorry.  I have corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Exchange account is set as default, so
when you get sub_olFolder, you are working with subfolder of Inbox of the message store that linked with Exchange account.

Comment: @Lunar Wolf responded to the answers by adding his own answer.  That answer was deleted because [s]he should have responded by comment.  The response to this answer was: "Victor Ivanidze Yes, the Exchange account is the default, but I cannot change it in the default account settings on IMAP, it is impossible."

Comment: My reputation of over 10K means I can see answers that have been deleted by a moderator.  You do not yet have such a reputation so I have copied Lunar Wolf's comment from his/her answer so you can see it.